# Java: how to convert each char in a string to '*' except for spaces

Tags: java, string

I have been set a task to convert each char in a string to * except for any spaces in that string (the string is user input), the one caveat is that I must use a for loop. My code is below... the current problem that I am having is that when I try to use the char in an if statement condition I am getting a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to Boolean" error. All help appreciated...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare vars
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "";
    int length = 0;

    //get name string
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    name = input.nextLine();

    //get length of name string
    length = name.length();

    //convert name string to array of characters
    char[] nameChars = name.toCharArray();

    //iterate over array of chars replacing each 
    // char with * and space with space
    for (int index=0;index==length;index++){
        //if the char is a space then do nothing
        if (nameChars[index] = ' ') {
        //else convert to *
        } else {
            nameChars[index] = '*';
        }
    }

    //convert array back to string and output
    String newName = new String(nameChars);
    System.out.println(newName);

    //close resources
    input.close();

}
```

Comment: `String newName = name.replaceAll("\\S", "*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` in place of `=` for the `if` condition checking as `==` is the relational operator while `=` is the assignment operator.

Change `index==length` to `index < length` otherwise your loop will never run! Initially `index = 0` while length is some positive value and `index!=length` then. So the loop will never run.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing all that code, try this:

```
String newName = name.replaceAll("\\S", "*");
```

The regex `\S` matches "any non whitespace character".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `==` instead of `=` like below:

```
if (yourChar == ' ') {
//your code ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Atimene. That solved the original problem, however now it is just outputting the original string without converting the chars to *. can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
if (nameChars[index] == ' ') {
    //else convert to *
    } else {
        nameChars[index] = '*';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code, then your condition is wrong, you're affecting the space `char` to the current `char` if the string `nameChars[index] = ' '` you must change it to `nameChars[index] == ' '`, note the double equal signe `==`.

However, I suggest you use this simple condition, cause you'll not do anything when the current `char` is a space `char`, then you don't have to check if it's a space char:

```
 if (nameChars[index] != ' ') {
             nameChars[index] = '*';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to invent a bicycle?
It's better to use the power of Java and exactly replaceAll method of String.class:

```
String input = "123 wer 456 zxcv!";
String result = input.replaceAll("[^ ]", "*");
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Java: how to convert each char in a string to '*' except for spaces

## You can just do it in one line without any loops..

```
String str = pw.replaceAll("[^\\s]", "*");
```

---

**TEST:**

```
String str1 = "ASDAS sad!@# !@#^% ?".replaceAll("[^\\s]", "*");
System.out.println(str1);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
***** ****** ***** *
```

Note: For `char[]`, you can use String.valueOf(yourArray).replaceAll().

Comment: your solution is a lot better than mine lol but this is part of an exercise designed to get us using loops and arrays so I had to use a loop in my answer. Thanks for the lesson though.

Answer (score -1):

```
String text = "It is a string";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "*"));
```

Output for the code will be : `** ** * ******`.

Note that it's easier to use a `StringBuilder` when you want to modify String. You need to remember that Strings are immutable.